# How to data model versioning use case in relational database

Tags: postgresql

i have use case where i need to increment the version for individual id by one

```
CREATE TABLE order (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  version INT NOT NULL,
);
```

order with order id 1 can have multiple revision say version 1,2 and 3

and if a new order with some different order id come there revision should again start from 1 and need to be increment by 1 if there is any change .

I know it can be taken care at application/program layer. I want to know if there is any constraint or option at DB layer.

Comment: Take a look at a [Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. (I changed the table name to "orders" and added field1 in order to have field to change)

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  version INT NOT NULL,
  field1 VARCHAR
);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_row_version()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  IF row(NEW.version) = row(OLD.version) THEN
        NEW.version=(select COALESCE(OLD.version,0)+1 where OLD.id=NEW.id);
        RETURN NEW;
     ELSE
        RETURN OLD;
  END IF;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';


    CREATE TRIGGER update_row_version BEFORE UPDATE ON orders FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_row_version();
```